# Do i need to install Java EE6 SDK even after i have installed netbeans 7.2 (complete package)?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-ee-6, netbeans-7.2

I am just starting with Java EE6. i have installed netbeans 7.2 though the sample applications based on java EE6 runs successfully. My question is do i still need to install Java EE6 SDK?? if not, then why is that Java EE6 SDK comes separately???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need it.

Java EE SDK is available as a standalone package because SUN's philosophy was not to require any specific environment (IDE) to do Java development.